# Select from same SQL table twice using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a site in PHP that lists the userbars of a forum, and have a column named 'isOfficial' - I've been able to select both NULL and IS NOT NULL seperately but am not sure how to select both.

As best as I can describe it, I'd like to be able to run these both from the same table:

First Query:

```
<?php include_once("assets/php/db.php");
      $sql = "SELECT ubFilename, ubGroupName, ubGroupOwner, ubOwnerLink, isOfficial, isActiveGroup FROM UBSUserbars WHERE NOT (isOfficial <=> NULL) ORDER BY ubGroupName";
      $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
      while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
```

Second Query:

```
<?php include_once("assets/php/db.php");
      $sql = "SELECT ubFilename, ubGroupName, ubGroupOwner, ubOwnerLink, isOfficial, isActiveGroup FROM UBSUserbars WHERE (isOfficial <=> NULL) ORDER BY ubGroupName";
      $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
      while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
```

And have them both output **separately** as such on the same page:

```
            <div class="cards">
                <?php
                    include_once("assets/php/db.php");
                    $sql = "SELECT ubFilename, ubGroupName, ubGroupOwner, ubOwnerLink, isOfficial, isActiveGroup FROM UBSUserbars WHERE NOT (isOfficial <=> NULL) ORDER BY ubGroupName";
                    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
                    while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
                    ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-card <?php echo $record['isActiveGroup'] === 'active' ? 'active-group' : ''; ?>">
                <img src="i/OGUsers/<?php echo $record['ubFilename']; ?>">
                <hr>
                <h4 class="group"><?php echo $record['ubGroupName']; ?></h4>
                <span>Owner: <a class="owner" href="<?php echo $record['ubOwnerLink']; ?>"><?php echo $record['ubGroupOwner']; ?></a></span>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: if you want to select both `NULL` and `NOT NULL`, then why bother including the `WHERE` condition? just omit the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

How about remove your WHERE clause in your SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT ubFilename, ubGroupName, ubGroupOwner, ubOwnerLink, isOfficial, isActiveGroup FROM UBSUserbars ORDER BY ubGroupName";
```

If you want to select both A and B value in a column your WHERE clause should be:

```
WHERE (table.column = A or table.column = B)
```

In your case, you want to select both NULL and NOT NULL value in `isOfficial` column so WHERE clause will be:

```
WHERE (isOfficial IS NULL or isOfficial IS NOT NULL)
```

which will becomes

```
WHERE 1
```

or no need WHERE clause

Your code will becomes:

```
<div class="cards">
<?php
    include_once("assets/php/db.php");
    $sql = "SELECT ubFilename, ubGroupName, ubGroupOwner, ubOwnerLink, isOfficial, isActiveGroup FROM UBSUserbars ORDER BY ubGroupName";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while( $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-card <?php echo $record['isActiveGroup'] === 'active' ? 'active-group' : ''; ?>">
        <img src="i/OGUsers/<?php echo $record['ubFilename']; ?>">
        <hr>
        <h4 class="group"><?php echo $record['ubGroupName']; ?></h4>
        <span>Owner: <a class="owner" href="<?php echo $record['ubOwnerLink']; ?>"><?php echo $record['ubGroupOwner']; ?></a></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to have two separate outputs on the same page, so the not null appears under a header 'Official Userbars' and null appears under 'Group Userbars'.

Comment: Literally don't worry I'm stupid what a great way to embarrass myself at 3am